Division function for binary numbers. Python
Hello everyone!
I am a beginner writing a simple program that performs four arithmetic functions between binary numbers. Writing functions, addition, subtraction and multiplication, there were no problems, but division... I don't understand how it can be implemented.
The main condition of my task is not to use ready-made functions and data. Two binary numbers that will be given to arithmetic functions must be in the form of a list ([1, 0, 1, 0] - for example) of type int. The division function should return the result as two inverted lists, the first is the quotient, the second is the remainder.
Successful arithmetic functions:
def add_zero(target: list[int], amout: int) -> list[int]:
    for index in range(amout):
        target.append(0)
    
    return target

def binary_addition(first_bin: list[int], second_bin: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    sum: int = 0
    carry: int = 0
    result_bin: list[int] = []

    max_size: int = max(len(first_bin), len(second_bin))

    add_zero(first_bin, (max_size - len(first_bin)))
    add_zero(second_bin, (max_size - len(second_bin)))

    for index in range(max_size):
        sum = first_bin[index] + second_bin[index] + carry
        result_bin.append(sum % 2)
        carry = sum // 2

    if carry > 0:
        result_bin.append(carry)

    return result_bin

def binary_subtraction(first_bin: list[int], second_bin: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    diff: int = 0;
    borrow: int = 0;
    result_bin: list[int] = []

    max_size = max(len(first_bin), len(second_bin))

    add_zero(first_bin, (max_size - len(first_bin)))
    add_zero(second_bin, (max_size - len(second_bin)))

    for index in range(max_size):
        diff = first_bin[index] - second_bin[index] - borrow

        if diff < 0:
            diff += 2
            borrow = 1
        else:
            borrow = 0;

        result_bin.append(diff)

    return result_bin

def binary_multiplication(first_bin: list[int], second_bin: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    temp_bin: list[int] = first_bin[:]
    result_bin: list[int] = [0]

    for number in second_bin:
        if number == 1:
            result_bin = binary_addition(result_bin, temp_bin)

        temp_bin.insert(0, 0);

    return result_bin

Write a division function, but quickly got confused.

Do you remember how you learned long division in grade school? You need to implement that same algorithm.

Here's a tutorial: https://www.wikihow.com/Divide-Binary-Numbers
